# An NSOutlineView with an empty datasource doesn't invoke its delegate methods?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Differently from a NSTableView, the delegate methods of an empty NSOutlineView are never invoked.

For instance, NSTableView method:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

is invoked even if there are not rows.

But, NSOutlineView method:

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
```

is not invoked if there are not items.

I need to write arbitrary text on the first row of my outlineView when it is empty. But I can't use the above mentioned method like I do for NSTableView.

What's the solution ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented `outlineView:numberOfChildrenOfItem:` to give a correct answer when passed `nil`?

From your description it seems to me that it should return 1 (your initial line) when passed `nil`, but I can't be sure without more code and/or information.